# What is a Text variable?

Tags: variables, text, constructor

I'm a beginner to programming so please understand if I don't get something really easy.

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBAVd.png)

My job is to implement the constructor in the Student class. However, I'm not sure what "-stuText:Text" means. Is there a type of variable called Text? and how should I implement the constructor?

Thank you so much

Comment: What language are you implementing this in? ```Text``` refers to the class that is defined next to student, labelled ```Text```

Comment: I'm doing this in Java. So how can I implement it?

Comment: well.. you have to start by implementing the ```Text``` class, once you do that you can use ```Text``` as a type in your constructor